# what does _doc represents in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am still trying to figure out what does _doc represents in elasticsearch?
From the documentation, two places I could find it's usage are:

1. While in sorting, it is recommended that _doc is better because the benefit of sorting by _doc is that elasticsearch can efficiently skip to the next matching document when moving to the next page (it will simply ignore all docs that have a smaller doc id than the last returned document).  [Source](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/12983#issuecomment-181118167)
2. Another reference to _doc was mentioned in [this](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/4492) git request which talks putting field name against _doc.

Can someone exactly tell what is _doc actually?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

`_doc` is a [mapping type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-type-field.html), which by the way is now [deprecated](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html).

A `mapping type` used to be a separate collection inside the same index. E.g. a `twitter` index could have a mapping of type `user` for storing all users, and a mapping of type `tweet` to store all tweets. Both of these types still belong to the same index, so you could search inside multiple types in the same index.

Since elaticsearch came out with the news to deprecate mapping types for several reasons, they forced v6 users to ONLY use 1 mapping type per index i.e. you can have either `user` or `tweet` inside the `twitter` index, but not both. **They further recommended to be consistent and use `_doc` as the name of the mapping type**. But this can literally be any string - dog, cat, etc. It is just recommended to be `_doc` because in v7 the mapping type field is completely going away. So if every index in elasticsearch only has 1 mapping type, then it would be easier to migrate to v7 because you just have to remove the mapping type and all documents would then directly come under the index.

Comment: This answer should be marked as correct, since this is the up to date information about the _doc term.

Comment: Thanks, didn't find this nowhere else!!

Answer (score 10):

From ElasticSearch 8.x version, only _doc is supported and it is just an endpoint name, not a document type.

> In 7.0, _doc represents the endpoint name instead of the document
> type. The _doc component is a permanent part of the path for the
> document index, get, and delete APIs going forward, and will not be
> removed in 8.0.
>
> Elasticsearch 8.x Specifying types in requests is no longer supported.
> The include_type_name parameter is removed.

[Schedule For Removal of Mapping Types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html#_schedule_for_removal_of_mapping_types)

Answer (score 4):

I believe these two use cases are not using the `_doc` terminology for the same purpose:

1. The keyword `_doc` for sorting is new in Elasticsearch 2 and is a replacement for the old scan and scroll way to efficiently paginate deep into the results of a query. There is no actual `_doc` field in the documents.
2. The `_doc` syntax to be used in the `_source` portion of a search (or get, update, etc) request has not been implemented as shown at the beginning of that git discussion, but using the [`fielddata_fields`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-fielddata-fields.html) field instead. It has nothing to do with the usage of `_doc` in sorting.

In the [scripting documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#_document_fields) you'll find a section about [document field data](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#_document_fields), that is extremely fast to read as it is stored in memory and is accessible using a similar `doc` syntax (that might add to the confusion).

Comment: Yeah.. I guess so.. For sorting by the got it seems it just only uses document id.. How is the question.. For second use case I was a little surprised to see use of a field name against it.. Regarding scripting as you mentioned this doc is completely different from this doc.. Aah confusion.. Let's wait for other community folks to reply

Comment: Apart for which value is actually used for sorting when specifying `"sort": "_doc"`, what is it that you do not understand in my answer? The content returned in `fielddata_fields` is exactly the same accessible by script using the `doc[fieldname]` syntax.