# When creating an index, what is the point of '_doc' when defining the mapping of the index?

Tags: elasticsearch

As I understand, when creating an index, you can define the fields that the documents will have in that index by defining a mapping

```
PUT person
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "firstName":{"type":"text"},
      "secondName":{"type":"text"},
      "age":{"type":"integer"}
    }
  }
}
```

But I also find a that queries are sometimes written like this, with a `_doc` inside the mapping

```
PUT person
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc":{
      "properties": {
        "firstName":{"type":"text"},
        "secondName":{"type":"text"},
        "age":{"type":"integer"}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What does putting `_doc` do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what does \_doc represents in elasticsearch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35747862/what-does-doc-represents-in-elasticsearch)

Comment: ^ The above comment is a duplicate of this question. For which elasticsearch version you're talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_doc` in the second mapping is loosely related to how mappings used to be defined before 7.0.

Instead of `_doc` it'd include the `type` of your document. With that being said, the 2nd mapping would work prior to 7.0 w/o a problem, and >=7.0 if you specified `include_type_name`, i.e. `PUT person?include_type_name=true`.

More info here: https://www.elastic.co/blog/moving-from-types-to-typeless-apis-in-elasticsearch-7-0

The idea of all of this is that one `index` should only include one `type` of document, thereby rendering the `type` first redundant and later deprecated.