# ElasticSearch 2.3 geo_point field throws error when string passed as arguement

Tags: node.js, typescript, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I' m using Elasticsearch 2.3 version with NodeJs 14. I was trying to assign string version of geo_point such as `'41.00445520431176,28.976772329847574'` instead of `{ "lat": 41.12, "lon": -71.34 }` an error thrown.

Here is the error from Nodejs

```
StatusCodeError: [mapper_parsing_exception] failed to parse
  at respond (/usr/src/app/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:349:15)
  at checkRespForFailure (/usr/src/app/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:306:7)
  at HttpConnector.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/connectors/http.js:173:7)
  at IncomingMessage.wrapper (/usr/src/app/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4991:19)
  at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:412:35)
  at IncomingMessage.emit (domain.js:537:15)
  at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1334:12)
  at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {
status: 400,
displayName: 'BadRequest',
path: '/users/_doc',
query: { type: 'user' },
body: {
  error: {
    root_cause: [Array],
    type: 'mapper_parsing_exception',
    reason: 'failed to parse',
    caused_by: [Object]
  },
  status: 400
},
statusCode: 400,
response: '{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_state_exception","reason":"Mixing up field types: class org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.StringFieldMapper$StringFieldType != class org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.geo.BaseGeoPointFieldMapper$GeoPointFieldType on field location"}},"status":400}',
toString: [Function (anonymous)],
toJSON: [Function (anonymous)]
```

Here is the error from Elasticsearch 2.3 which is running in docker

```
 [2021-10-19 09:29:04,326][DEBUG][action.index             ] [Ghost Dancer] failed to execute [index {[users][_doc][AXyX4gRD7BhLOaBJFlNV], source[{"company_title":"eren-company","country":{"country_code":"tr","country_name":"eren-test","id":225},"createdAt":"2017-11-13T11:19:21+00:00","experience_level":"0","experience_month":0,"experiences":{},"first_name":"eren-test","id":1,"last_name":"eren-lastname","location":"41.00445520431176,28.976772329847574","user_type":"created.user_type"}]}] on [[users][3]]
 MapperParsingException[failed to parse]; nested: IllegalStateException[Mixing up field types: class org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.StringFieldMapper$StringFieldType != class org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.geo.BaseGeoPointFieldMapper$GeoPointFieldType on field location];
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseDocument(DocumentParser.java:154)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:309)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.prepareCreate(IndexShard.java:529)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.prepareCreateOnPrimary(IndexShard.java:506)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.prepareIndexOperationOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:215)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.executeIndexRequestOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:224)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:158)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:66)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryPhase.doRun(TransportReplicationAction.java:639)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryOperationTransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportReplicationAction.java:279)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryOperationTransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportReplicationAction.java:271)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.RequestHandlerRegistry.processMessageReceived(RequestHandlerRegistry.java:75)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$4.doRun(TransportService.java:376)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mixing up field types: class org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.StringFieldMapper$StringFieldType != class org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.geo.BaseGeoPointFieldMapper$GeoPointFieldType on field location
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.FieldMapper.updateFieldType(FieldMapper.java:397)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.FieldMapper.updateFieldType(FieldMapper.java:53)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseDynamicValue(DocumentParser.java:622)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseValue(DocumentParser.java:442)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObject(DocumentParser.java:262)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseDocument(DocumentParser.java:122)
        ... 17 more
```

And finally here is the mapping from ElasticSearch.

```
{
    "users": {
        "mappings": {
            "user": {
                "_meta": {
                    "model": "AppBundle\\Entity\\User"
                },
                "properties": {
                    "company_title": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "boost": 5,
                        "analyzer": "turkishIcu"
                    },
                    "country": {
                        "properties": {
                            "country_code": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "country_name": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "id": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "createdAt": {
                        "type": "date",
                        "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
                    },
                    "experience_level": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    "experience_month": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "experiences": {
                        "properties": {
                            "company_name": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "boost": 5,
                                "analyzer": "turkishIcu"
                            },
                            "position": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "boost": 5
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "first_name": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "boost": 10,
                        "analyzer": "turkishIcu"
                    },
                    "id": {
                        "type": "integer",
                        "boost": 0,
                        "norms": {
                            "enabled": true
                        }
                    },
                    "last_name": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "boost": 10,
                        "analyzer": "turkishIcu"
                    },
                    "location": {
                        "type": "geo_point"
                    },
                    "user_type": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Besides all of the above; When I try to pass `{ "lat": 41.12, "lon": -71.34 }` I get the error below.

```
 StatusCodeError: [invalid_type_name_exception] Document mapping type name can't start with '_'
     at respond (/usr/src/app/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:349:15)
     at checkRespForFailure (/usr/src/app/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:306:7)
     at HttpConnector.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/connectors/http.js:173:7)
     at IncomingMessage.wrapper (/usr/src/app/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4991:19)
     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:412:35)
     at IncomingMessage.emit (domain.js:537:15)
     at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1334:12)
     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {
   status: 400,
   displayName: 'BadRequest',
   path: '/users/_doc',
   query: { type: 'user' },
   body: {
     error: {
       root_cause: [Array],
       type: 'invalid_type_name_exception',
       reason: "Document mapping type name can't start with '_'"
     },
     status: 400
   },
   statusCode: 400,
   response: `{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"invalid_type_name_exception","reason":"Document mapping type name can't start with '_'"}],"type":"invalid_type_name_exception","reason":"Document mapping type name can't start with '_'"},"status":400}`,
   toString: [Function (anonymous)],
   toJSON: [Function (anonymous)]
 }
```

As I said before;

- Elasticsearch => v2.3
- NodeJs => v14
- [Elasticsearch module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticsearch)

Thank you for your help.

Sincerely Eren;

Comment: seems like _doc is deprecated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35747862/what-does-doc-represents-in-elasticsearch

Comment: @TingLee Yes I noticed that. But I did not add `_doc` to the query. Package does itself. I tried to switch `@elastic/elasticsearch` but due to old version of elasticsearch, the new package does not recognize the elasticsearch 2.3 instance. Therefore I need to use old package.

Comment: I realized that `type` parameter is not added to the url. I guess package is broken at this point.

Comment: @TingLee you can check my answer

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. The problem was occurring because of the `apiVersion` switching to the proper version fixed the issue.

TL;DR;

```
import { Client } from 'elasticsearch';
this.client = new Client({
   host: configService.get<string>('ELASTICSEARCH_HOST'),
   apiVersion: '5.6',
});
```

I did some research in the package itself and found out that if you did not specify the `apiVersion` it automatically imports master api and master api formats the url like below, which is wrong.

```
  urls: [
    {
      fmt: '/<%=index%>/_doc/<%=id%>',
      req: {
        index: {
          type: 'string'
        },
        id: {
          type: 'string'
        }
      }
    },
    {
      fmt: '/<%=index%>/_doc',
      req: {
        index: {
          type: 'string'
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

The whole `_doc` issues come from this formatting, it does not care the mapping name. I think this is a bug. Then I checked the other apis and they were like below;

```
  urls: [
    {
      fmt: '/<%=index%>/<%=type%>/<%=id%>',
      req: {
        index: {
          type: 'string'
        },
        id: {
          type: 'string'
        }
      }
    },
    {
      fmt: '/<%=index%>/<%=type%>',
      req: {
        index: {
          type: 'string'
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

They include the mapping name which was called type. Then I specify the `apiVersion` for the `Client` problem fixed right away.